# Terrain ploughing simulation

Tags: animation, particles, physics

I am trying to model something moving through a terrain and disrupting it (think Star Wars Imperial Destroyer size thing crash landing on a planet)

What I want to do:

- model terrain being displaced by the moving object
- have the texture change accordingly to terrain disruption
- specifically, an upper layer with a satellite image and a lower level of dirt/rock. I want the parts on top to keep the original picture until mixed with other terrain.

What I have tried so far:

- Dynamic Brush -> Displace:
  Works, but just crushes the terrain down.
- Liquid simulation with extremely high viscosity:
  Very close to what i want to achieve, but there seems to be no way to project a texture on it and keep it there

Ideas:

- Particles. But how?

Comment: Would 'ploughing' be a fair description of what you're looking for?

Comment: Oh yes it would! I was thinking at way larger scale but it would be the same thing!

Comment: Inspiration ... https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLr1CoIYb0ED3K1-pbRJbnR8-l2auqcmS1&si=Tcu0ZHjPe7ZDaDdO.  https://youtu.be/B6VnSEj6Tok?si=VpSZLiA47wy6vLMk ... BTW with the same data used by DynPaint you can control texture appearance.

Comment: Also would be helpful to share some visual reference ... such scale collision of imperial destroyer with earth, sounds to me like a job for smoke sim :)